# Using SUMIF Excel to calculate excess total

Tags: excel

I'm working out the time per week I spend that exceeds 280 minutes in an activity.  I have a SUMIF function that I want to display only the excess time, not the 280 minutes + excess.

My statement looks like so:

```
=SUMIF(B8:H8,">280")
```

I don't have a sum_range, but I'm not sure what I would enter here to achieve only the excess minutes total?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMIF by itself will not do what you want but if we add a COUNTIF we can acheive the correct output:

```
=SUMIF(B8:H8,">280") - (COUNTIF(B8:H8,">280")*280)
```